# Ruby on rails without http request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, server-side

I'm currently developing a server that can get data over the internet from specific device i have and log it into a database. Unfortunately I dont have control on the way this device communicate.

Currently I set an IP adress and a port number and the device will open a socket and send a string. I dont really want to develop a server from scratch and i would much prefer to base on a web server. but the data is a plain string and not a full http request.

Is there a way around it using Ruby on rails ? Is it possible to do with other web-server-based technology ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a regular old ruby socket to receive the string.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an application that [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) would be useful for, if you want a pre-made node+rails app which would do what you want check out [compound at GitHub](https://github.com/1602/compound) mentioned in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527482/ruby-on-rails-and-node-js)